# Stuck in a circular wait condition. Need help to get out

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, mutex

I am currently developing an multi-threaded application that does raw video data playback using Qt. There are three worker threads. One is Reader Thread, one is Processor Thread and the other is a Video Output Thread. The reader thread will read raw data into a buffer, then the processor will process the raw data and put displayable data into a frame FIFO.

My raw data buffer is implemented as a Hash table which means every frame index will have its corresponding raw data. Once the processor finish processing the raw data one a certain frame it deletes the raw data from the raw data buffer so that the reader can read data into the buffer once it comes back to a frame it read before.

I now have problem when implementing pause functionality. What I wanna do is when the video is pause, the processor and reader should quit and video output thread will just display one same frame in the fifo. I can now exit from processor thread properly. The reader seems to get into a circular wait condition situation.

Here are some code for my reader thread.

```
    void ReaderThread::run()
    {
        forever
        {
        //inputState_ is internal state of the reader
        if (inputState_ == stop) 
            // return from run() if state is stop
            return;              
        //dataBuffer is a pointer to raw data buffer object
        //This grab the mutex lock of the raw data buffer
        dataBuffer->lock() 
        //frameIndex is counter for frame  
        if (dataBuffer->contains(frameIndex_))
        {
            //mutex_ is a member variable of type QMutex
            mutex_.lock();
            //Wait for the data to be removed. 
            dataBuffer->waitForWritable(); 
            mutex_.unlock();
         }
        dataBuffer->unlock();

        // Read data to raw frame buffer
        uchar rawDataPointer = readRawData(); 

        dataBuffer->lock();
        //insert the frame number and corresponding pointer into the hash table
        dataBuffer->insert(frameIndex, rawDataPointer); 
        //wake up processor.
        dataBuffer->wakeForReadable()
        dataBuffer->unlock();

        mutex_.lock();
        if (inputState_ == play)
           frameIndex++;
        mutex_.unlock();
        }
    } 

    void ReaderThread::stop()
    {
        mutex_.lock();
        inputState_ = stop;
        //Wake up the reader if the reader is waiting 
        dataBuffer->wakeAllWritable(); 
        mutex_.unlock();

        // Wait for run() to return.
        QThread::wait();
     }
```

Processor thread is implemented similarly. I stop the processor at first and it succeeded. I call ReaderThread::stop() from main thread when I want to return from run(). But I got into a circular wait condition, where if the reader thread is waiting on the buffer to be writable, it never will unlock mutex_ of this reader thread. As a result, the stop will always get block and the program just hangs. I tried not to lock the mutex_ before the dataBuffer->waitForWritable(), however, I got into a situation where the reader thread will wait on the writable right after the dataBuffer->wakeAllWritable() is called.

Can anyone suggest a way to resolve this issue? I have been trying hard to figure out how to get out of this circular wait condition situation but didn't quite work out as I am still new to threaded programming.

Comment: Shouldn't you lock the dataBuffer before calling wakeAllWritable()? That way you can remove _mutex.lock both from waitForWritable and wakeForWritable. Let me now how it goes.

Comment: @Franco, this makes sense. I will try it out when I am back to the office. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should lock dataBuffer before using it in stop(), like this:

```
void ReaderThread::stop()
    {
        mutex_.lock();
        inputState_ = stop;
        mutex_.unlock();
        //Wake up the reader if the reader is waiting 
        dataBuffer->lock();
        dataBuffer->wakeAllWritable(); 
        dataBuffer->unlock();            

        // Wait for run() to return.
        QThread::wait();
     }
```

in this way you can remove the mutex_.lock() & unlock from the other method:

```
    //dataBuffer is a pointer to raw data buffer object
    //This grab the mutex lock of the raw data buffer
    dataBuffer->lock() 
    //frameIndex is counter for frame  
    if (dataBuffer->contains(frameIndex_))
    {
        dataBuffer->waitForWritable(); 
     }
    dataBuffer->unlock();
```

Comment: Yea, I have tried it out. It works out properly and I don't need many member mutex for the threads. It seems like a trivial one and was because I didn't fully understand the mechanism of QWaitCondition. Thank you very much @Franco.